# Monitor Spark 2.X with graphite

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, monitoring, graphite

I would like to monitor the execution of my Jobs with graphite. I want to do this to have the HDFS I/O rate and the number of tasks in exectution. I followed this tutorial : http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/27/monitoring-spark-with-graphite-and-grafana/ but if I use their option to submit the job :

```
--files=/path/to/metrics.properties \
--conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties
```

I get an error that it can't find the file :

```
16/10/05 13:21:22 ERROR metrics.MetricsConfig: Error loading configuration file metrics.properties
java.io.FileNotFoundException: metrics.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Also I tried to input an absolute path accessible by all my nodes (in a mounted dir) this remove the error but they are missing informations in graphite (like executor.threadpool)

Does anyone use Spark with Graphite and can help me ? Or maybe there is a better tool than Graphite ?